# Invalid Column name generated by EFCore on a one-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, one-to-one, ef-core-3.0

I am trying to set a one to one foreign key relationship  in my context class but I keep getting the error below. I found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526786/getting-invalid-column-name-employmenttypeentityemploymenttypeid-in-entity-fram) but that didn't seem to solve my issue because I am specifying the relationship explicitly in the model. I confirmed that:

- Server object has a reference to a ServerList object (the public virtual ServerList object)
- ServerList object has a reference back to the Server (the navigation property??) via (the public virtual Server object)

I tried to solve this by adding the annotation `ForeignKey("ServerId")` the the ServerList.ServerName column, but that didn't work. Why is EFCore trying to create this column? Why didn't the ForeignKey annotation fix the problem?

> Invalid column name 'ServerListServerName'.

My Context class:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Server>(entity =>
    {   
        entity.HasOne(d => d.ServerList)
            .WithOne(p => p.AwsServer)
            .HasForeignKey<Server>(d => d.ServerName);
    });
```

Server.cs:

```
public partial class Server
{
    [Key]
    public int ServerId { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PockAdvCompany> Companies { get; set; }
    public virtual ParentServer ParentServer { get; set; }
    public virtual ServerList ServerList { get; set; }
}
```

ServerList.cs:

```
public partial class ServerList
{
    public virtual ICollection<PockAdvCompany> Companies { get; set; }
    public virtual Server AwsServer { get; set; }

    [Key,Column("ServerId")]
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it is because your `ForeignKey("ServerId")` is not a property in `ServerList` but instead a property in `Server`
It should be the name of property that point that class to its parent.
Also FK in `ServerList` is `string`, but the PK is `int`
try this

```
public partial class ServerList
{
    public virtual ICollection<PockAdvCompany> Companies { get; set; }
    public virtual Server AwsServer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AwsServer")]
    public int ServerId { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this help